# Any way to clean up this complex aggregate function?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using Postgres, but I'm fine with a generic solution to this (and you can ignore the text aggregation if you want).

With the following table setup:

```
id  ref_id  user_id  start_time  duration text
100 2000    1        15000       200      hello
101 2000    1        16000       300      world
102 2000    1        22000       400      foo
103 2000    2        17000       500      bar
104 2000    2        21000       600      baz
```

I'm trying to use the minimum integer timestamp (ms or whatever) and use that as the basis for windowing my query. The idea being that the *absolute* minimum across all users it the window for the conversation. So if i looked at 5000-unit windows, I'd have 2 blocks (15000-20000, 20001-25000).

Expected output:

```
ref_id  user_id  block  sum(duration) count(*) text
2000    1        1      500           2        hello world
2000    1        2      400           1        foo
2000    2        1      500           1        bar
2000    2        2      600           1        baz
```

I've gone through multiple iterations of self join and window, but I can't get it more compact than three nested queries.

```
select user_id, block, string_agg(text, ' '), sum(duration)
from 
    (select user_id, FLOOR((start_time - t1.st)/5000) as block, start_time, text, duration
    from table t0
    inner join 
        (select id, min(start_time) as st from table group by 1) as t1
        on t0.ref_id = t1.ref_id
    order by 1, 2, 3) t2
group by 1, 2;
```

I think the reason I need the third is because I couldn't order by start_time, and it matters for some of aggregations (text concatenation, for example).

I'd love some help if anyone's an expert!

Comment: the example data and sql don't match: there's no column called `id` in the example data.

Comment: I'll edit my data to make it more verbose. I thought it was irrelevant, but perhaps I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not surer why that "block" is so important, but you can remove one level of subqueries:

```
select user_id, FLOOR((start_time - minstart)/5000),
       string_agg(text, ' '), sum(duration)
from (select user_id,  as block, 
             start_time, text, duration,
             min(start_time) over (partition by id) as minstart
      from table t0
      ) t
group by 1, 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming the field called `id` in the example sql is a typo and should be `user_id` as specified in the example data*

The simplest way to write this query would be:

```
SELECT
  user_id
, FLOOR((start_time - mst)/5000) + 1 block
, SUM(duration)
, STRING_AGG("text", ' ')
FROM mytable, (SELECT MIN(start_time) mst FROM mytable) minst
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

You don't need any window functions or nested queries. Here, the `,` separating the two relations in the `FROM` clause performs a `CROSS JOIN` (*or Cartesian Product*) implicitly. This is how most people start writing joins in SQL queries.

However, using `,` to implicitly mean `CROSS JOIN` is often perceived as bad style, so instead the above query can be written as:

```
SELECT
  user_id
, FLOOR((start_time - mst)/5000) + 1 block
, SUM(duration)
, STRING_AGG("text", ' ')
FROM mytable CROSS JOIN (SELECT MIN(start_time) mst FROM mytable) minst
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Also, from your example sql attempt and desired output, it seems that you'll have to add 1 to `FLOOR((start_time - minst)/5000)` to get the blocks to start from 1, 2, ...